# Passing context to interactive node shell leads to "TypeError: sandbox argument mus have been converted to a context"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to start an interactive node shell with some objects already initialised. The following code however leads to:

```
var repl = require('repl')

var x = 11,
    y = 21

var con = {}
con.x = x
con.y = y

repl.start('> ').context = con
```

This happens when I start and try to access one of the context variables:

```
node .
> y
TypeError: sandbox argument must have been converted to a context.
    at TypeError (native)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:250:27)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:412:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:826:14)
```

However `repl.start('> ').context.y = y` works.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign(repl.start('> ').context, con)`

When typing `repl.start('> ').context`, the object is quite large. I guess assigning `context` to a custom object misses some properties.

Comment: This should be reported as a bug, if it hasn't been